# Tem como tirar o botão de fechar formulários no VBA/Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Quero tirar o botão de fechar de alguns formulários no VBA/Excel.

Por exemplo, estou personalizando a apresentação de algumas mensagens para diferenciar das opções do VBA que são pouco atrativas.

Além de usar imagens, cores e fontes diferentes, seria interessante que o formulário que irá apresentar a mensagem não apresentasse o botão de fechar (o "X" no canto superior direito), obrigando o usuário a optar somente por "Sim" ou "Não", por exemplo, e adicionar o botão "Cancelar" quando for o caso desta opção existir também.

Tem como fazer isso?

Encontrei algumas soluções, mas são para versões antigas do VBA e para 32 bits, não consegui adaptá-las para funcionarem em 64 bits.

Comment: Removi a sinalização desculpe o mal entendido. @leo

Comment: Valeu! Obrigado.

Comment: Parece que tem duas perguntas suas com o mesmo título. @leo

Comment: Percebi, acabei de remover, grato mais uma vez.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solução que encontrei está no site do **Tomas Vasquez Sites**.

[DESABILITANDO O BOTÃO FECHAR DE UM USERFORM NO VBA](http://www.tomasvasquez.com.br/blog/microsoft-office/vba/desabilitando-o-botao-fechar-de-um-userform-no-vba)

Este é o código:

```
Option Explicit

' Fonte: Tomas Vasquez Sites
'
' http://www.tomasvasquez.com.br/blog/microsoft-office/vba/desabilitando-o-botao-fechar-de-um-userform-no-vba

'==========================================================================
' Retira o botão "X" (fechar) do Formulário, permanecem a barra e o caption
'==========================================================================

Private Declare Function FindWindowA Lib "user32" _
         (ByVal lpClassName As String, _
          ByVal lpWindowName As String) _
             As Long

Private Declare Function GetWindowLongA Lib "user32" _
         (ByVal hwnd As Long, _
          ByVal nIndex As Long) _
             As Long

Private Declare Function SetWindowLongA Lib "user32" _
         (ByVal hwnd As Long, _
          ByVal nIndex As Long, _
          ByVal dwNewLong As Long) _
             As Long

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim hwnd As Long

hwnd = FindWindowA(vbNullString, Me.Caption)

SetWindowLongA _
 hwnd, -16, _
 GetWindowLongA(hwnd, -16) And &HFFF7FFFF

End Sub


Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)

Dim hwnd As Long

hwnd = FindWindowA(vbNullString, Me.Caption)

SetWindowLongA _
 hwnd, -16, _
 GetWindowLongA(hwnd, -16) Or &H80000

End Sub


Private Sub ButtonSair_Click()

Unload Me

End Sub
```

**O formulário precisa de um botão de fechar neste caso.**